# Angular Material Table Dynamic Columns without model

Tags: dynamic, interface, angular-material, datasource

I need to use angular material table without model, because I don't know what will come from service.

So I am initializing my `MatTableDataSource` and `displayedColumns` dynamically in component like that :

**TableComponent :**

```ts
ngOnInit() {

this.vzfPuanTablo = [] //TABLE DATASOURCE

//GET SOMETHING FROM SERVICE 
this.listecidenKisi = this.listeciServis.listecidenKisi;
this.listecidenVazife = this.listeciServis.listecidenVazife;

//FILL TABLE DATASOURCE 
var obj = {};
for (let i in this.listecidenKisi ){
    for( let v of this.listecidenVazife[i].vazifeSonuclar){
        obj[v.name] = v.value;
    }
    this.vzfPuanTablo.push(obj);
    obj={};
}

//CREATE DISPLAYED COLUMNS DYNAMICALLY
this.displayedColumns = [];
for( let v in this.vzfPuanTablo[0]){
    this.displayedColumns.push(v);
}

//INITIALIZE MatTableDataSource
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.vzfPuanTablo);
}
```

---

The most important part of code is here :

> ```ts
> for( let v in this.vzfPuanTablo[0]) {
>    this.displayedColumns.push(v);
> }
> ```

I am creating `displayedColumns` here dynamically, it means; even I don't know what will come from service, I can show it in table.

For example `displayedColumns` can be like that:

- ["one", "two" , "three" , "four" , "five" ]

or

- ["stack","overflow","help","me]

But it is not problem because I can handle it.

---

But when I want to show it in HTML, I can't show properly because of
`matCellDef` thing:

**TableHtml :**

```xml
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumns; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{disCol}}</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> {{element.disCol}}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

My problem is here:

> ```xml
> <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> {{element.disCol}} < / mat-cell>
> ```

In fact, I want to display `element."disCol's value"` in the cell, but I don't know how can I do that.

Otherwise, everything is ok except this `element."disCol's value"` thing.

---

When I use `{{element.disCol}}` to display `value of element that has disCols's value` , all cells are empty like that:

[image]

Other example that using `{{element}}` only:

[image]

---

**Also as you can see:**

1. Table datasource is changing dynamically. It means I can't use `{{element.ColumnName}}` easily, because I don't know even what is it.

   - First Example's displayedColumns = ['Vazife', 'AdSoyad', 'Kirmizi', 'Mavi', 'Yesil', 'Sari'];
   - Second Example's displayedColumns = ['Muhasebe', 'Ders', 'Egitim', 'Harici'];
2. `matHeaderCellDef` is correct , because it is using {{disCol}} directly.

*But I need to read disCol's value, and display `element.(disCol's value)` in the cell.*

**How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found solution :) 
It is very very easy but i could't see at first :)
only like that :

> ```
>         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> {{element[disCol]}}
>         </mat-cell>
> ```

I must use `{{element[disCol]}}` only in HTML.

Now , everything is ok:)

Comment: Can you please send me full sample code to create dynamic column from API and fill grid

Comment: @Uttam I've added a full example below

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the clean, simple answer.  I was bracing myself for another deep dive into "angularity".   :--)

Comment: @mevaka, Could you please provide full code to create dynamic columns. I am facing the issue while adding the colums.  
I am adding the columns based on button click. i mean if 5 buttons are dere . by click on each button , columns will be adding and also rows are increasing. 
if i add 5 columns , 5 rows are coming, but i need only one row.

Comment: @srikanth to add onto the columns you'll want ```displayedColumns.push("newCol")```

Comment: As long as your array of objects' keys structure is consistent you can also use something like this to dynamically generate the columns: `this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(data[0]);`

Comment: @mevaka my displayedColumns is an array of objects (it has id, label, etc) , so ```element[disCol] ``` doesn't work for me, I tried with ```element[disCol.id] ``` , ```element.id``` and ```element.disCol.id``` , but no luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 17):

For a full working example based on @mevaka's

Where `jobDetails$` is the array of items.

`columns$` is equvilent to `Object.keys(jobDetails$[0])` so is just a `string[]`

```js
<table mat-table [dataSource]="jobDetails$ | async">
  
  <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of (columns$ | async); let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{disCol}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[colIndex]}}</td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="(columns$ | async)"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: (columns$ | async)"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can we apply different column size using css if we have a dynamic table? I want to covert my static table to dynamic to support 2 different views.

Comment: @ChandreshMishra I don't see why not, give it ago!

Comment: but where and how to apply the css class as tr and td will be generated by ngFor?

Comment: Add a "data type" attribute to your abstract row model, which can be used to generate a CSS class for each data and header cell.   E.g. numeric types should be right aligned.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel Could you please elaborate a bit? Have a similar requirement.

Comment: It's been a while ... but here goes: Instead of a simple list/array of strings, each "Column Definition" can be a data structure that gives name, display name, datatype, required/optional, etc. for each column.  Each row and column value can refer to its column definition by column index (either a simple numeric array index or an associative array by column name).   Thus, you can locate enough information to define CSS class names by datatype or any other information you keep in the column definition objects (1 per column) in every row of that column.   Similar to virtual data in C++/MFC.

Comment: Have a look at the answer from @rjsteinert, which illustrates what I'm trying to describe.

Answer (score 13):

I've tried my best to boil a dynamic table down to the minimum. This example will display any columns given an array of flat objects with any keys. Note how the first object has an extra "foo" property that causes an entire column to be created. The DATA const could be some data you get from a service. Also, you could add a "column ID -> label" mapping into this if you know some common property names you'll be getting the JSON. See the stachblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-mat-table-ep7hb8).

```js
import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

const DATA: any[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'sdd', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', foo: 'bar'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'}
];

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-table-example',
  styleUrls: ['dynamic-table-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'dynamic-table-example.html',
})
export class DynamicTableExample implements OnInit {

  columns:Array<any>
  displayedColumns:Array<any>
  dataSource:any
  
  ngOnInit() {
    // Get list of columns by gathering unique keys of objects found in DATA.
    const columns = DATA
      .reduce((columns, row) => {
        return [...columns, ...Object.keys(row)]
      }, [])
      .reduce((columns, column) => {
        return columns.includes(column)
          ? columns
          : [...columns, column]
      }, [])
    // Describe the columns for <mat-table>.
    this.columns = columns.map(column => {
      return { 
        columnDef: column,
        header: column,
        cell: (element: any) => `${element[column] ? element[column] : ``}`     
      }
    })
    this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);
    // Set the dataSource for <mat-table>.
    this.dataSource = DATA
  }
 
}
```

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: This example really helped me to get started, and the closest to the documentation. Only difference is that now it's recommended to use mat-table "Directive":

<td **mat-cell** *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</td>

Comment: How would you add other cell definitions, like buttons, checkboxes, selects, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

## Dynamically render datatable from source (input type='checkbox')

I have a needs to render the column dynamically, I also expect to render cell value as checkbox. My code was edited from [Angular example table with filtering](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/table/examples) and got the dynamic rendering part from @Jack. Hopefully code attached below can provide a brief idea to junior like me.

### What I did was

1. wrap `<td mat-cell... </td>` with `<div *ngIf="condition"></div>`

```
<div *ngIf="disCol === 'username'">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[disCol]}}</td>
</div>
<div *ngIf="disCol !== 'username'">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <input *ngIf="element[disCol] == 'Yes'" type="checkbox" />
        <input *ngIf="element[disCol] == 'No'" type="checkbox" checked/>
    </td>
</div>
```

2. It is also worth mentioning that I am on Angular 16, the import statement is slightly different with older version. Older version basically import directly from `'@angular/material'`

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
```

#### dynamic-tb.component.html

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumns; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{disCol}}</th>
      <div *ngIf="disCol === 'username'">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[disCol] == undefined ? "-NA-" : element[disCol]}}</td>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="disCol !== 'username'">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <input *ngIf="element[disCol] == 'Yes'" type="checkbox" />
          <input *ngIf="element[disCol] == 'No'" type="checkbox" checked/>
        </td>
      </div>
    </ng-container>"

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

#### dynamic-tb.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-tb',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-tb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-tb.component.css']
})
export class DynamicTbComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  dataSource: any;
  ELEMENT_DATA: any[] | undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.displayedColumns = ['username', 'feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3'];
    this.ELEMENT_DATA = [
      { username: "Jonah", feature_1: 'Yes', feature_2: 'No', feature_3: 'No' },
      { username: "Alan", feature_1: 'Yes', feature_2: 'No', feature_3: 'Yes' },
      { username: "John", feature_1: 'No', feature_2: 'Yes', feature_3: 'No' },
      { username: "Ann", feature_1: 'Yes', feature_2: 'No', feature_3: 'Yes' },
      { username: "Lee", feature_1: 'No', feature_2: 'No', feature_3: 'No' },
      { username: "Royce", feature_1: 'Yes', feature_2: 'Yes', feature_3: 'No' },
      { username: "Suzzy", feature_1: 'No', feature_2: 'No', feature_3: 'No' },
    ];
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
  }

}
```

#### dynamic-tb.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { DynamicTbComponent } from './profiles.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

@
NgModule
({
  declarations: [
    DynamicTbComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatTableModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    DynamicTbComponent
  ]
})

export class DynamicTbModule {}
```

#### dynamic-tb.component.css

```
/* Structure */
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.example-header {
  min-height: 64px;
  padding: 8px 24px 0;
}

.mat-form-field {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}

/**
  Added by me
*/
th, td {
  width: 100px;
}
```