# Dynamic table Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

Im Building a dynamic table with Angular material libary.

```
<table dir="rtl" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" multiTemplateDataRows>


  <ng-container *ngFor='let column of originalthis.displayColumns'>

    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.key">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column.value}}</th>

  *****<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.{{column.key}} }}</td>*****

    </ng-container>

  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr (click)="chooseRow(row)" class="example-element-row" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </tr>

</table>
```

How can i connect my data to the matCellDef {{ data.{{column.key}} }} isnt seems to works.

Comment: Have you tried `{{ data[column.key] }}`?

Comment: Have you tried     {{data.get(column.key)}} ??

Comment: @KapilThakkar  Yes, but i get: 'ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.get is not a function'

Comment: @yurzui  it works, and for further more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868019/angular-material-table-dynamic-columns-without-model

Comment: Please post example link