# How can I create an Angular Material Design table with infinite columns, for known number of rows?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have created an HTML table which will generate infinite **columns** based on the 
 number of **rows** in the input data. I've tried to use [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868019/angular-material-table-dynamic-columns-without-model) as an example, but I'm struggling to convert my HTML to Angular Material design. Any suggestions?

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iga2fk)

Since Angular material tables are column-based (and I couldn't find a way to iterate over the rows within them) I got stuck pretty quickly.

I couldn't get angular material tables working in the StackBlitz, so here is a copy paste of my code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="newLicenseDS">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of newLicCol; let idx = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{disCol}}</th>
        <ng-container *ngIf="idx==0">
           <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">{{e[0]|json}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="idx==1">
           <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">{{e[1]|json}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="idx==2">
           <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let e[2]">{{e|json}}</td>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="newLicCol"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: newLicCol"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why? Is this there any real reason? Performance will bite you.

Comment: It doesn't have to be infinite, but I can't tell how many columns there will be in advance, it's likely far less than a hundred columns, but I can't guarantee that, which is why I'm trying to write it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only thing you need is "loop" the matColumnDef. -see that we use `[matColumnDef]` and `{{element[col]}}`

If your table is like

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="col">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{col}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[col]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

You only need transform your data and indicate the displayedColumns.
You can do in a ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
    const head = this.data.map(x => x.name)
    const data: any[] = [];
    this.data.forEach((x, index) => {
      Object.keys(x).forEach((k, index2) => {
        data[index2] = data[index2] || {}
        data[index2][head[index]] = x[k]

      })
    })
    this.displayedColumns=head;
    this.dataSource = data.slice(1); //I remove the first element that was the "header"
  }
```

See in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nmwlq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

**Update** about the question not use a mat-table else a simple table, just we need iterate using displayedColumns. Some like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">{{col}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of dataSource">
     <td *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">{{row[col]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without Angular Material ? I am using Angular 8

Comment: @Rishabh,  of course, you has yet the "displayedColumns" and the "dataSource". it's only iterate over this, I updated the answer (the stackblitz with the two models are in this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nmwlq-ixxajd?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html. NOTE: You can see the "data" using a `<pre>{{displayedColumns|json}}{{datasource|json}}</pre>` to see how work

Comment: thanks for the reply, it works perfectly fine. But I have realised that this is not exactly what I am trying to do, my array is a simple string array and need to display it in 4xn way. 4 rows and n number of columns. I am trying how to move to a new column after the 4th element. I have been able to do this using ul li

Comment: @Rishabh, some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160729/angular-ngfor-four-elements-on-row/68164750#68164750)?

Comment: Yeah something like that Using ul li I am able to achieve this setting a height to the ul ngfor on li

Comment: the code in the SO only transform an array uni-dimensional in an array bi-dimensional, but I'm not pretty sure that can help you in case use ul and li :(