# Angular - ngfor* four elements on row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an array of skills, every skill has an id and a name: `{ id:0, name:Angular }`. I'm trying to display four skills on a row in a table, but I don't know how. I need to change that `ng-container` somehow, but I don't know.
The result is something like: HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT JAVA SPRING ANGULAR, but I want only four on a row.
My code is:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="skills" class="skillsColumn">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="skillsColumn">Skills
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="skillsColumn">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of row.skills">
          {{ skill.name + " " }}
        </ng-container>
      </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What is the result? What is the problem?

Comment: The skills are printed like this: Angular Java Javascript Spring CSS HTML, but I want only four on a row.

Comment: If you want only fpur, and discard others then simply slice the array - *ngFor="let skill of row.skills.slice(0,3)"

Comment: I want all skills to be displayed, but on a row can be maximum four skills

Answer (score 1):

Can you please elaborate?
you want 4 skills in a row? which 4? is it 4 different skills per row?

If you just want the first 4 you can simply do this

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of skills; let i=index">
     <div *ngIf="i%4 == 0"></div>
     {{ skill.name }} 
 </ng-container>
```

but if that's what you want maybe you should change the logic behind the html

Comment: Yes, the number of skills can be unlimited and I want to display all skills, but just  four skills on a row.          First row: Html, CSS, Java, Spring                                                                                            Second row: JS, Angular, Python, C++

Comment: then I think my answer can solve it pretty easily for you. btw I edited it, so copy the new code if it works for you.

Comment: I want all skills to be displayed, but on a row can be maximum four skills

Comment: so you mean you want a line break after 4 skills?
should it be in the same table cell or another one?

Comment: Yes, a line break after 4 skills. It should be in the same table cell

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of rows. You can use iterating over values to group them or use some like

```
values=["Html","CSS","Java","Spring","JS","Angular","Python","C++"]
rows=this.values.map((_,x)=>this.values.slice(x*4,(x+1)*4))
    .filter(x=>x.length)
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfxmfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)