# How to bind json data with Angular material table to create dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to populate a `mat-table` with data received from backend in json format. Since there is key associated with each value, I want to use that as column header instead of using a model. I went through the official doc which has only support for static column values. Anyone has any docs or github repos dealing with this issue. I came across one question in stack overflow itself [Angular Material Table Dynamic Columns without model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868019/angular-material-table-dynamic-columns-without-model).
But I have issue with understanding what happens under the comment `//GET SOMETHING FROM SERVICE`. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

//GET SOMETHING FROM SERVICE

```
this.listecidenKisi = this.listeciServis.listecidenKisi;
this.listecidenVazife = this.listeciServis.listecidenVazife;
```

These are both service function that calls back end APIs.

So this.listecidenKisi and this.listecidenVazife are array data from back end.

Please refer following for Angular Http Client.

https://angular.io/guide/http

http://prntscr.com/pvz2f1

Comment: So if i convert the js object from backend to key-value pairs, will I be able to substitute the service call with that data and finally use it in a material table? i dont have ssms installed in my local system to try it right now.