# How to dynamically bind angular material table with data from backend?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to bind mat-table with data from backend api based on this [Angular Material Table Dynamic Columns without model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868019/angular-material-table-dynamic-columns-without-model). Here is the `.ts` file content

```
    technologyList = [];
      listTechnology = function () {
        this.http.get("https://localhost:44370/api/admin").subscribe(
          (result: any[]) => {
            this.technologyList = result;
            //creating table begins here
            var displayedColumns = Object.keys(this.technologyList[0]);
            var displayedRows = Object.entries(this.technologyList[0]);
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.technologyList);
            }
```

I am getting response from backend as `technologyList`which is
>

```
    Array(2)
    0: {id: 1, technologyName: "Python", description: "Python123", commission: "20", imageURL: "https://cutt.ly/gePgUvn", …}
    1: {id: 2, technologyName: "Ruby", description: "Python123", commission: "30", imageURL: "https://cutt.ly/gePgUvn", …}
    length: 2
```

I am trying to bind this with html using `.html` file as
>

```
        <div>
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

            <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumns; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{disCol}}</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> {{element[disCol]}}
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
    </div>
```

The output is a blank white block. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Response after the proposed change
[output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb2TR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-nojudj?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

```
  displayedColumns = [];
  dataSource;


 listTechnology = function () {
        this.http.get("https://localhost:44370/api/admin").subscribe(
          (result: any[]) => {
            this.technologyList = result;
            this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(this.technologyList[0]);
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.technologyList);
        })
  }
```

Comment: Show the complete output of result

Comment: I mean `console.log(result)`

Comment: You have shown `{id: 1, technologyName: "Python", description: "Python123", commission: "20", imageURL: "https://cutt.ly/gePgUvn", …}`

Comment: `...` does't help, you need to copy and paste the complete object so that I can see the properties

Comment: Its solved. Apart from the missing value shown as null each cell for adminUser, rest all is working fine. I removed native html table tags `tr`,`td` from the html file and its working fine. Thank you so much:)

Comment: Incase i need to add edit/delete actions in a column corresponding to each row, how can I do that?